# How to loop TS file in m3u8 playlist

Tags: video, ffmpeg, stream, video-streaming, m3u8

I want to create m3u8 playlist, like this:

```
#EXTINF:-1,LIVE STREAM
http://example.com/live01.ts
```

When this file ended I want repeat in loop.
After live01.ts ended, need to start again and do this infinity in loop.

Is this possible?

Comment: Try nesting the .m3u8 within itself.

Comment: Work only with VLC player, but doesn't work in KODI.
I need to play in KODI. Any another solutions?.

Comment: Seen [this](http://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=155071)?

Answer (score 7):

It's not possible with a static playlist like that.

First, you'll have to have a `#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY` tag before the `#EXTINF` tag so the player knows the timestamps on the video/audio frames aren't going to continue in order.

Second, and more importantly, you'll need a `#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:<number>` and/or `#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE:<number>` at the head of the file that increments at the same rate as the duration of that chunk of video. The player is going to be re-requesting the playlist (until it sees `#EXT-X-ENDLIST`) and without incrementing those values it will continue to assume that `http://example.com/live01.ts` is the first chunk in the sequence.

If you're serving the M3U8 file directly and you have a sleep command on your system that supports milliseconds, I'd suggest something like this:

```
file="/path/to/file.m3u8"
duration="1.337"

make_playlist() {
  echo "#EXTM3U"
  echo "#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:${1}"
  echo "#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE:${1}"
  echo "#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY"
  echo "#EXTINF:${duration},"
  echo "http://example.com/live01.ts"
  echo
}

for ((x=0;;x++)); do
  make_playlist "${x}" > "${file}"
  sleep "${duration}"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not an official feature of m3u8. The looping itself must be done as a player setting.

Comment: Thanks for answers. I found option in KODI Playlist - Repeat All, and  this solved my problem!

Comment: Not necessarily. You can add segments in a loop dynamically to emulate a loop, such as in ads. The player doesn't need to know, it thinks it's a continuous live stream.